# Does exists a virtual pdf printer that works with command line and no dialogs?

Tags: pdf

i'm developing a module in .NET. I need to print some report directly to a virtual printer pdf. 
I need to pass all parameters (like filename) via command line and it's required to not show dialogs.
Which virtual pdf creator i can use ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see PDFCreator , http://www.pdfforge.org  http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator

> Quoted from Help:
>   Using Profiles
>   You can define multiple profiles. Each profile has a given set of settings that define the settings for the output file and what is done with it (print after saving, calling actions etc.)
>   To learn more about the available options, please refer to the other sections of this chapter.